# Deployed Simple HelloWorld with Spring MVC app (without web.xml) gives 404 error

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, spring-4

[image]

I am newbie to Spring MVC with annotations, I have worked with Spring MVC XML Configuration earlier. I get 404 error when I try to hit the url http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp. I have written three classes:
1. AppIntializer
2. AppConfig
3. AppController
Following piece of code:

```
 package com.demo;
        public class AppIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
            private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "com.demo.config";

            @Override
             public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

            System.out.println("Initializing Application for " + servletContext.getServerInfo());

            // Create ApplicationContext
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            applicationContext.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);

            // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
            DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

            servlet.addMapping("/");
            servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        }
    }

    package com.demo.config;
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        @ComponentScan("com.demo")
        public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        }

    package com.demo.web.controller;
    @Controller
    public class AppController {
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello World: Spring MVC without XML configuration";
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HelloWorldApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorldApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>                       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have tried to run it:

```
mvn clean install
mvn tomcat7:run
```

Console output:

```
 C:\Users\workspace_new\HelloWorldApp>mvn tomcat7:run
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building HelloWorldApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ HelloWorldApp >>>
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorldApp ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\harleen.dhingra\workspace_new\HelloWorldApp\src\main\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorldApp ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO]
    [INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ HelloWorldApp <<<
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorldApp ---
    [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
    [INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\harleen.dhingra\workspace_new\HelloWorldApp\target\tomcat
    [INFO] create webapp with contextPath:
    Jun 22, 2016 11:11:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 22, 2016 11:11:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Tomcat
    Jun 22, 2016 11:11:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
    Jun 22, 2016 11:11:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

I am not getting error on console, when I hit http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/ or http://localhost:8080/  I should get output as "Hello World: Spring MVC without XML configuration" instead I get 404 error

Comment: I think you missed the `@Controller` annotation on your `public class AppController`

Comment: I have added the @Controller on AppController but still I get 404 error.

Comment: Do you heard from `Spring-Boot`? I would suggest to use it because its build on to build full Spring applications without configuration files.

Comment: @Patrick I have tried with Spring-Boot and it worked. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Missing **@Controller** annotation in the Controller class. 
Your controller class should be like

```
package com.demo.web.controller;
@Controller
public class AppController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World: Spring MVC without XML configuration";
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**
**Here are two updates to this answer**
***Solution 1***
Add this code to your AppInitializer class

```
applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
```

**If solution didn't worked then change your code like this :**

**Solution 2**
I did it slightly different way and it worked.
Here are the changes:

> 1. move your AppInitializer class to this package(config folder) & change it to **com.demo.config**
> 2. Use .register method, instead of .setConfigLocation as shown below

```
package com.demo.config;
    public class AppIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
         public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        System.out.println("Initializing Application for " + servletContext.getServerInfo());

        // Create ApplicationContext
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: oops I missed that, I have added the @Controller on AppController but still I get 404 error. Is there anything else to look at.

Comment: did you cleaned the project? @Harleen

Comment: I ran two commands again mvn clean install & mvn tomcat7:run from cmd but I get same error 404 once I hit http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/ in browser.

Comment: i did the same test here, it worked.
i ran command "mvn clean install".  i simply put this war file into tomcat webapps folder and click on start.bat inside tomcat bin directory. & what is Config_Location in applicationContext.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION); @Harleen

Comment: CONFIG_LOCATION is a package location for AppConfig class. I tried the same way I have put the war file "HelloWorldApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" in webapps and ran startup.bat. I get logs like: Jun 22, 2016 1:12:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive HelloWorldApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war but when I tried to hit http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/. I get 404 error, I am not getting where I am wrong. @Tahir

Comment: I have tried both your solutions neither of them worked for me. When I try to hit url in browser I get same 404 error. @Tahir

Comment: can you post your Directory SnapShot to your question? :) @Harleen

Comment: I have added project directory structure. May be it will help you to answer my question  :) @Tahir

Comment: thanks for the setup, got this working on AWS first try with your help